# how to get clicked item details from list while using *ngFor in Angular4 / Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-template, angular2-ngfor

I'm trying to fetch details of item when it was clicked but unable to get circular item details.. The requirement is need to fetch details and display in a Modal created in Ionic

Template Code:

```html
<div class="row" *ngFor="let circularitem of circularmonthdata; let i = index">
  <div class="col">{{circularitem.Circular_date}}</div>
  <div class="col">{{circularitem.Circular_name}}</div>
  <div class="col">
    <a class="btn btn-small" (click)="openModal(i)">
      <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Component Class Code: I'm new to use Modal in angular please let me know how to populate a modal from class

```js
public openModal(index) {
  console.log("value is", index);
}
```

Comment: You could just pass `circularitem` instead of `index` to your `openModal` handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `circularItem` as a parameter:

```
(click)="openModal(circularItem)"
```

in .ts :

```
public openModal(item){
    console.log(item);
}
```

Comment: working fine.. Thanks Augustin for quick response.. could you please let me know how can i display this data in Modal..

Comment: Do you use Angular Material? Or a custom modal component?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention.. the Modal should be created in Ionic - I'm not sure whether Angular Modal will support or need to create custom Modal..

Comment: I let you refer to Ionic ModalController [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/). Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have this on your view

```html
 <button mat-raised-button class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="openModal(circularItem)" >Do Something</button>
```

And on your component you will have this.

```js
  openModal(circularItem){

    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent,dialogConfig);
    dialogRef.componentInstance.circularItem = circularItem;

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(data => {
      //do something
    });
  }
```

Remember to import MatDialog and MatDialogConfig:

```js
import { MatDialog,  MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material';
```

And declare your dialog on your constructor:

```js
constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}
```

Lastly you need to make sure you define the value you are passing to your dialog component.

```js
export class MyDialogComponent implements OnInit {
    circularItem; //or like this circularItem : CircularItem;

    constructor(){}

    // Then you can access it here like this

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.circularItem);
    }

}
```